# Enforcing android permissions within the same app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

Here is a scenario. My app has

- BroadcastSenderActivity
- SampleBroadcastReceiver

I am using the `sendBroadcast(intent, permission)` method to send out my broadcast because I would like only my SampleBroadcastReceiver to receive the broadcast message and prevent other receivers in my app from receiving the message.

***Note:*** All receivers are registered for the same action but at the time of broadcast based on the system conditions the message will be broadcasted with varying permissions.

From the documentation I learnt that I need the following in the manifest :

1. Need to declare `<permission android:name="com.example.MYPERMISSION" 
       android:label="my_permission" 
       android:protectionLevel="normal"></permission>`
   in the manifest
2. Have this stmt to request for the permission which is at the app level `<uses-permission android:name="com.example.MYPERMISSION"/>`

***QUESTION*** -

- Instead of app-level permission request how can I request permission only for a particular component in my app? eg. SampleBroadcastReceiver (see code below). Is it possible?*
- What's the purpose of the `<android-permission>` tag which is available for all inidividual components? Can it serve my purpose ?

  AndroidManifest

  ```
      .........
  ```

  ```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.activities.BroadcastSenderActivity"
        android:label="BroadcastSenderActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <!-- **************************************  RECEIVER ******************************************* -->
  <receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastTest.SampleBroadcastReceiver"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.example.ACTION_BROADCAST_SEND" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastTest.BroadcastReceiver_1"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.example.ACTION_BROADCAST_SEND" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastTest.BroadcastReceiver_2"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.example.ACTION_BROADCAST_SEND" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  ```

---

```
    public class BroadcastSenderActivity extends Activity {

public BroadcastSenderActivity() {

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(Logger.TAG, "BroadcastSenderActivity - onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.broadcast_tester);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendBroadcastBtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            Log.d(Logger.TAG, "BroadcastSenderActivity - sending the broadcast");
            broadcastIntent.setAction(com.example.ACTION_BROADCAST_SEND);
            BroadcastSenderActivity.this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent, com.example.MYPERMISSION);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can secure each separate component with a specific permission. This is the `android:permission="..."` attribute that can be applied to each component separately. This allows you to require different permissions, for example, to launch a specific `Activity`, start a specific `Service` or use a specific `BroadcastReceiver`. This attribute indicates that the **application** needs to hold the specified permission in order to use the specific component.

An **application** holds a set of permissions. These permissions are requested in the manifest by the `<uses-permission>` tags. The user is shown this list when the application is **installed** and the application is granted these permissions **upon installation**.

When you send a broadcast, usually all installed and/or registered `BroadcastReceiver`s are able to see this broadcast. When you use the method `sendBroadcast(intent, permission)` the `permission` parameter is used to control which receivers are able to see the broadcast. However, this permission checking is also done at the **application level**. This means that if an **application** has been granted the specified permission, then all of that application's `BroadcastReceiver`s will be able to see the broadcast.

Therefore, what you want to do is not possible using the Android permission mechanism. Because an **application** either has or does not have a specific permission, you cannot have fine-grained control over which **components** can be used by a specific application.

Hopefully this answers your question.

**EDIT: Alternative suggestion:**

Since this is all within a single application, you should be able to manage this yourself. Personally, I think using the Android permission framework for this is overkill. You can just add an appropriate **extra** to the broadcast `Intent` and use that for controlling access to the receivers. Or, you can define 2 different `Intent` actions, and use that to control access.